# curl windows: the provided file handle is not writable

Tags: php, windows, curl

I have a random "hang without errors" while executing curl requests. I'm trying to detect the origin as the web server and php logs don't show any errors, so I tried to enable `CURLOT_STDERR`.

I have the following code:

```
$file = 'curl.txt';
$curl = curl_init();
$curl_log = fopen($file, 'rw');
var_export(is_writable($file));
$url = 'http://www.google.com';

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => 1,
    CURLOPT_STDERR          => $curl_log,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
rewind($curl_log);
$output= fread($curl_log, 2048);
echo '<pre>'. print_r($output, 1). '</pre>';
fclose($curl_log);
```

`is_writable` returns true, but curl execution dies with the following error:

> curl_setopt_array(): the provided file handle is not writable

I'm running PHP 7.0.15 Fast CGI on a Windows Machine.

It seems the CURL user doesn't have write permissions, but I can write on that file using other PHP functions.

Comment: `if(!$curl_log){
throw new \RuntimeException('fopen failed');
}
var_dump($curl_log);`

Comment: Hi, fopen works and returns a valid file resource.

Comment: how about `var_dump(fwrite($curl_log,'test'));` ?  it should return int(4)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for your help hanshenrik.

`var_dump(fwrite($curl_log,'test'));` returned 0.

So I changed the line  `$curl_log = fopen($file, 'rw');` to `$curl_log = fopen($file, 'a');` and problem solved.